# How to make height map more pronounced?

Tags: displacement

[image]

So I am watching CG Geek's tutorial on [how to create a Star Destroyer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A245FOyn9Ak&t=229s), and I'm pretty much finished with it, but there's one small problem that I am having. On his tutorial, his displacement map on the model is so pronounced and stick out more.My displacement map stick out a little, but barely at all. It just looks flat.

I tried using a math node on the image texture in order to amplify the map, but it doesn't seem to do anything.In the video, CG geek is using Blender 2.78. I'm using 2.82. Maybe that has something to do with it?

How do I get me displacement map to stick out more like in CG Geek's video?

Here it the reloaded [Blender file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah2aL3r7RO3ThOk2Rsi9Wv7861ySWA?e=riUdxD) (with images).

Comment: your node organization seems weird but anyway you didn't pack the image in the blend file so it doesn't appear, could you please reupload the file with the image packed?

Comment: @moonboots I reuploaded the whole folder with the Blender file. I think the Blender File needs the Blend1 file to be downloaded with it for the images to appear. I placed the PNG image in the file as well.

Comment: @moonboots 
On a separate note, for the nodes, I believe I just followed along with CG Geeks tutorial. Although it may be slightly different. However, whenever I mess with nodes, I just kind of plug and play to see what works. Any tips or links that could help with organization?

Comment: SMH, you need to pack the image called "Depth_4.exr", the one you use as a Bump, in the UV Editor you need to select it and go to Image > Pack so that it gets packed in the blend fil itself.

Comment: He seems to be using true (both) displacement, are you doing that as well? (Disclaimer: didn't really watch the tutorial)

Comment: @moonboots When I opened the file, Depth_4.exr was in there, but I repacked the image into the file and reuploaded in the link above. I also added a separate folder with all of the displacement maps in case it goofs again.

Comment: @Leander I actually didn't have both selected. Although, when I do select both Displacement and Bump under the Settings tap under Materials, it really messes up my side texture. I tried adding a Subtract node with my Multiply node like in the video, but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: @moonboots converting it to a JPEG actually did help. The only problem is that when I set the Displacement (under the Settings Tap on the Material settings) to Displacement and Bump, it distorts the texture way too much. Do you think it could be a problem on how I UV unwrapped the mesh?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if what I said is true  ;)  I'm going to test again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the problem was not the format but your node organization, it's a bit messy, choose one of those below. Also make sure that you've correctly unwrap your object and that the different parts have the right material.

[image]

Comment: Still no such luck unfortunately. The top one node arrangement doesn't really make the texture pop out, and the bottom one displaces the texture too much. I tried redoing the UV unwrapping for the parts of the mesh that are using the texture, but that didn't seem to help.

Comment: Mmh weird because it works fine with me

Comment: damn. Are you using both bump and displacement on your material settings?

Comment: here is my file: https://pasteall.org/blend/414f5b92f11c43fabf51e8189837ea18

Comment: To switch from a solution to the other just click on the Material Output you want to test

Comment: Note that when you are using "bump" as normal you are not altering the geometry, but changing (faking) the shading, whereas if you use displacement, and set the displacement to "real" you can generate real geometry, that will be more "pronounced"

Comment: Yes as Susu says you can generate real displacement if you activate the option in the Properties panel > Material > Settings > Surface > Displacement and choose Displacement Only or Displacement and Bump, but you don't have enough topology and it would not be a good idea in your case, so keep it fake

Comment: @moonboots  So basically it's better if I just leave it as bumps (fake), right? Sounds like there's no way around it.

Comment: Would you agree, @susu ?

Comment: Yes fake works fine  ;)  for this kind of object a real displacement would need a huge subdivision, it's not interesting